# How do I solve these definite integrals?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, area

[image]

Alright, I am being asked to solve $\int_{-4}^{4}f(x)dx$,$\int_{4}^{6}f(x)dx$,$\int_{6}^{9}f(x)dx$,$\int_{-4}^{9}f(x)dx$. $$$$So for $$\int_{-4}^{4}f(x)dx$$ I thought the way you solved these would be $f(4)-f(-4)$, which would be $0-(-1)$ which would $=1$. But, that isn't correct, and I am not sure on how to go about solving these. for $\int_{4}^{6}f(x)dx$ I did the same and got $f(6)-f(4)$ which $=4$ and was correct, so I am really lost right now. How do I solve these correctly, thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not the difference of the function values, it the difference in an antiderivative, but that's not easy to do. Instead use geometry to get the area of each piece.

Comment: So I am not supposed to do any actual "calculus" just do it by pieces? That's what it means by geometrically?

Comment: Yep. That's exactly right. The point is you should only resort to the "big guns" when you have to. When things are easy (i.e. using geometry instead) you should go for that.

Comment: Gotcha. I suppose I was overthinking it, thanks!

Comment: Split this up into rectangles and triangles. The area between the line below the x-axis and the x-axis is negative and the area between the line above the x-axis is positive and integral is just a measure of the area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments have already answered the question, but in a nutshell:  The definite integral from $a$ to $b$ of $f(x)dx$ is the sum of the areas bounded by $f(x)$ above and the $x$-axis below, minus the sum of the areas bounded by $f(x)$ below and the $x$-axis above.

One other observation:  The intervals in the first three parts form the interval in the fourth part: $[-4,4], [4,6], [6,9] \to [-4, 9]$.  So, having found the first three parts, add those results to get the fourth:

$$\int_{-4}^{9}f(x) dx = \int_{-4}^{4}f(x) dx + \int_{4}^{6}f(x) dx + \int_{6}^{9}f(x) dx.$$

Comment: Yeah, thanks for clearing that up some more. The help is really appreciated.